# Typescript IntelliSense throw error: Property 'customSelect' does not exist on type 'Knex<any, unknown[]>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, knex.js, nrwl-nx

I have a typescript IntelliSense problem.

I want to add a new method to `knex` in typescript [as written in the docs](https://knexjs.org/) (search "Extending Query Builder").

So I create `knex.d.ts` in `@types` folder with this content:

```
// knex.d.ts
import { Knex as KnexOriginal } from 'knex';
declare module 'knex' {
  namespace Knex {
    interface QueryBuilder {
      customSelect<TRecord, TResult>(value: number): KnexOriginal.QueryBuilder<TRecord, TResult>;
    }
  }
}
```

And add this code to my `tsconfig.base.json`:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types", "@types" ],
  }
}
```

But I got an error in typescript:

> Property 'customSelect' does not exist on type 'Knex<any, unknown[]>'.

[image]

The error is point to the [foo-lib](https://github.com/wizardnet972/nx-knex/blob/main/libs/foo-lib/src/lib/foo-lib.ts#L4)
at `authDb.customSelect();` and  `authDb.select().customSelect();`.

**What I am doing wrong??**

I create a repo to reproduce the problem: https://github.com/wizardnet972/nx-knex

Comment: You should check 2 things:
1. You publish your custom ts definitions with your package
2. Your consumer package defines the path to these ts definitions

Comment: I'm facing same issue. did you get any solution ? @shlomi